# Building Docker on OpenShift WIndows Cluster

Tags: docker, openshift, docker-for-windows, windows-container

Trying to build my Windows Container on OpenShift Windows Cluster using Build Strategy.

A build strategy of type Docker means at OpenShift side it pull the repository and points to the Dockerfile and created a build.

I have a simple dockerfile based on Windows base image and when building this it fails with below error

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022-amd64
COPY hello.txt C:
RUN ECHO "HELLO-WORLD"
CMD ["cmd", "/C", "type C:\\hello.txt"]
```

Below is the build log error

```
Trying to pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022-amd64...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:fcfdcf7069fa97d174a5fc8b1cfffbf4f15099246e0d53770bf40a7268bd9b77
Copying blob sha256:6a0972e4a21b1e21e65ee97fd7f7b548b42f85db2bcb8c941555d9a7111d7e22
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
Trying to pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022-amd64...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:fcfdcf7069fa97d174a5fc8b1cfffbf4f15099246e0d53770bf40a7268bd9b77
Copying blob sha256:6a0972e4a21b1e21e65ee97fd7f7b548b42f85db2bcb8c941555d9a7111d7e22
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
Trying to pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022-amd64...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:fcfdcf7069fa97d174a5fc8b1cfffbf4f15099246e0d53770bf40a7268bd9b77
Copying blob sha256:6a0972e4a21b1e21e65ee97fd7f7b548b42f85db2bcb8c941555d9a7111d7e22
Warning: Pull failed, retrying in 5s ...
error: build error: failed to pull image: After retrying 2 times, Pull image still failed due to error: trying to reuse blob sha256:fcfdcf7069fa97d174a5fc8b1cfffbf4f15099246e0d53770bf40a7268bd9b77 at destination: adding layer with blob "sha256:fcfdcf7069fa97d174a5fc8b1cfffbf4f15099246e0d53770bf40a7268bd9b77": processing tar file(no such file or directory): exit status 1
```

Also tried specifying proxy but no luck.

Any pointers would be helpful, not much resources found related to windows container

Comment: This seems like an issue with pulling the image, can I ask why you're using the -amd64 image, rather than the regular ltsc2022 image?